# adding word counter to html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

This html form and the related php code works pretty well together. I need to add a word counter. Any suggestions.

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">

<fieldset>

   <input type="hidden" name='counter' value='2'/>

  <p><label for="heading1"></label>
  <input type="text" name="heading1" size="60" /></p>
  <p><label for="input1"></label>   
   <textarea cols="width" rows="height" name="input1">...</textarea></p>


   <p><label for="heading2"></label>
   <input type="text" name="heading2" size="60" value="first para title..."></p>
   <p><label for="input2"></label>
   <textarea cols="width" rows="height" name="input2">...</textarea></p>

<br />
<fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="" />
<input type="reset" value="" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The related php code is found below.

```
<?php

$count=$_REQUEST['counter'];

for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
echo "<p>" . $_REQUEST['heading'.$i] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $_REQUEST['input'.$i]. "</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Provide an own idea, then we can help you! Do you want to use AJAX, only JS, when do you want to count words (while typing or after form submission)?...

Comment: Yes: learn basic JavaScript ;)

Comment: As a side-note, it is significantly easier to work with a form when you use `name="heading[]"` instead of `heading1`, `heading2`...

Comment: Don't rely on a hidden input to count the words. Get PHP to do it.

Comment: @rybo111 There's no harm in using JS to provide instant user feedback, provided it is also backed up by a server-side validation.

Comment: Word Counter? That means when user types or erases a letter then the counter keeps changig like 1,2,3,etc

Comment: #strauberry would like to render word count followed by form submission.

Comment: Exactly. But it's a hidden input.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var output = document.getElementById("counter"),
textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

 textarea.onkeyup = function (event) {
     var words = textarea.value.split(" ");
     output.value = words.length;
 };
```

To make it easier, add IDs to your HTML elements like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="0"/>
 <textarea cols="width" rows="height" name="input2" id="textarea">...</textarea>
```

What this does: Every time the user releases types a letter into the textarea it will take the contents, split it on spaces and counts the number of words which is inserted into your hidden `counter` field. When the form is submitted the number of words will also be sent to the server.

However, if you don't need the number of words in the client (for instance showing the user how many words she has typed) then I suggest you do this in PHP. Look at the `str_split` function.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<textarea name="input1" onkeyup="window.alert(document.getElementsByName('input1')[0].value.trim().split(' ').length);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript, with an event on the change in the textarea(s).
Then you count the word when typing and update the counter.